# Why does this code produce a "non-exhaustive patterns in case" error?

Tags: haskell, case, guard

I was trying out the following example given in [this tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad#Complete_and_Concrete_Example_1).

What I could not understand is how the case guards for the cases `'c'` and `_` don't use the `on` at all?

I modified the code as given [here](http://hpaste.org/74941#line30), but then when I run it I got the error "Non-exhaustive patterns in case":

```
*StateGame> main "accaaaa"
*** Exception: state1.hs:(27,5)-(31,36): Non-exhaustive patterns in case
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Can you explain what you think the `on` does in the first two cases? And why you think it'd make sense to add it to every case?

Comment: On StackOverflow, it's preferred that you include the code directly (indent by four spaces to make it show as code) than providing links to hpaste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A case guard is a boolean expression which is checked after successfully matching the corresponding pattern. If it evaluates to `True`, that branch is chosen. Otherwise, Haskell will keep trying each case from top to bottom.

In your example, all the cases have the guard expression `on`:

```
case x of
   'a' | on -> ...
   'b' | on -> ...
   'c' | on -> ...
   _   | on -> ...
```

Thus, when `on` is `False`, none of the branches can be chosen, so you get a "Non-exhaustive patterns in case" exception.